# Unity, How to login to an ASP.NET API using external providers securely?

Tags: asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, authentication, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

Is this secure enough to authenticate the user? The user will press a button to open an URL in native browser with a provider name and "device" token that is randomly generated. The user will see the login provider and when successfully logged in, the page will show, "please go back to the game".

Here is a diagram on how it should work.
[image]